# Can anyone tell me which arguments will execute in Java if they are entered from both command prompt and the main method?

Tags: java

I recently encountered a problem in Java certification exam that had something like Java Classname Argument[0] Argument[1] Argument[2] Argument[3]. The main method also had 4 different arguments. In the certification exam, I was asked which Arguments would execute. I wasn't sure what to answer. Can someone provide more clarity about picking arguments from Java command prompt as well as the main method. Sorry, I am not that good in Java so please dont feel bad if the question isnt properly structured ?

Thanks,

Comment: When run from the command line, the main function would receive any arguments provided - when creating a new instance of the class, then the constructor would receive any arguments that the creator passes in.

Comment: Arguments don't "execute".

Comment: May be the question was something like 'java arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 ..., which one among argX  would execute'? In this case the correct answer the arg0 is a class to 'executed', the rest the args of main().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [Entry Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java),

> Java programs start executing at the main method, which has the following method heading:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> public static void main(String... args)
> public static void main(String args[])
> ```

[JLS-12.1.1. Load the Class Test](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.1) really covers everything up to and including [JLS-12.1.4 Invoke `Test`.main](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) which reads

> Finally, after completion of the initialization for class `Test` (during which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have occurred), the method `main` of `Test` is invoked.
>
> The method main must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter ([§8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) whose declared type is array of `String`. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> public static void main(String... args)
> ```

Comment: The question(Not the real one) was soomething like Java Ejava Cat Dog Lion Tiger.. and in the main function, the arguments were like running flying walking jumping. How do I know which arguments out of these will execute. Is there any material I can refer to ?

Comment: All of them; you'll get the actual `String[]` {"Ejava", "Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Tiger"}. What you do with it, is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a Java program, you supply the JVM executable with the name of the main class. That class must have a method with signature

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

The `args` array will be filled with the command line arguments that follow the class name. This is the only way that command line arguments reach your program. There is no ambiguity or issue here.

Comment: *When you execute a Java program, you supply the name of the main class* this is not entirely true. You execute the JVM (`java.exe` or just `java`), supply arguments to it like `-cp`, `-Xms` and `-Dwhatever`, then you supply the complete name of the class to execute, and the additional parameters from here will be the arguments that will be stored in `String[] args`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you supply the name of the main class as an argument to the JVM executable. How is this at odds with what I wrote?

Comment: Only there you have a Java program. From that point, the rest of the arguments would be arguments for your Java program. For example, in C/C++ apps, the name of the app is an implicit argument to the application, and this doesn't happen in Java apps, but it does for the JVM.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I hadn't intended it to be read like that. Perhaps the phrasing was a little unclear. I've reworded it. Thanks for the pointer.